# Insert id's from one table to another based on another column

Tags: mysql

New MySql user here.

Suppose I have two tables:

Table1 rownames -> external_id, name, location

Table2 rownames -> id, name, type, value, year

What I want to do is to write a script where it populates in Table2.id the value from Table1.external_id, if there is a match in Table1.name and Table2.name.

I thought about something like this, but unfortunately its not working.

```
insert into Table2.id
    select Table1.external_id
    where Table1.name = Table2.name
```

Comment: you can not create **alias** in *insert* statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do an insert here, what you will do is create a whole bunch of duplicates. What you need is an update join

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 set table2.id = table1.external_id
WHERE Table1.name = Table2.name;
```

You don't need any script for this, just type this into the mysql client, phpmyadmin etc

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
insert into Table2 (id)
    select Table1.external_id
    where Table1.name = Table2.name;
```